# How to deploy/release a python script created by anaconda?

Tags: python, deployment, anaconda, release, conda

I have installed anaconda and write a one file py script. I want to create a zip package that user can just unzip the file and double click a file (.bat or .py) for run.

How can I create such zip file?

I read the doc regarding the conda environment but it seems it is still something for the development machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyInstaller, cxfreeze, py2app for create standalone exe for windows and .tz for Linux and Mac it helps to distribute your code to others with or without python

Comment: Thanks. But is there another other option if I want not to create a .exe? Let's say I want the user can be able to modify the script on their PC?

Comment: You can use setuptools and [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) to create setup.py . So user can able to access your source.